# Как использовать bredcrumbs

Tags: python, django

подскажите пожалуйста как использовать breadcrumbs в django1.6/python3.3.

я установил модуль [отсюда](https://github.com/chronossc/django-breadcrumbs/). затем добавил 'breadcrumbs' в INSTALLED_APPS.

затем добавил 'breadcrumbs.middleware.BreadcrumbsMiddleware' в MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

затем добавил   'django.core.context_processors.tz', 'django.core.context_processors.request' в TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

затем добавил в views.py:

```
def inner_page(request, slug='index'):
    request.breadcrumbs("qwerty", request.path_info)

    t = loader.get_template('inner_page.html')
    c = None

    if slug == 'index':
        content = Page.get_main_pages(request)
        c = RequestContext(request, {
            'title': 'Main page',
            'content': content,
            'slug': 'index',
        }, [custom_proc])       
    else:
        content = Page.get_page(slug)
        c = RequestContext(request, {
            'title': slug,
            'content': content,
            'slug': slug,
        }, [custom_proc])

    try:
        c != None
    except NameError:
        raise Http404
    else:
        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

затем добавил в base.html:

```
<div>   
    {% for breadcrumb in request.breadcrumbs %}
    <a href="{{ breadcrumb.url }}">{{ breadcrumb.name }}</a>{% if not forloop.last %} &raquo; {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
<div>
```

в результате в консоль выводится следующее [сообщение об ошибке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/err.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, видимо, в самом django-breadcrumbs. Модуль явно давно не обновлялся, поищите среди [форков](https://github.com/chronossc/django-breadcrumbs/network) или сделайте свой с исправленным кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Также можно посмотреть аналоги модуля на этом ресурсе [djangopackages.org](https://djangopackages.org/search/?q=breadcrumbs) там видно когда обновлялись последний раз, так же есть сравнение модулей.
А вообще такие простецкие и мелкие задачи лучше самому делать а не использовать для этого модуль а потом париться с ним и не понимать почему он не работает. Больше времени потратите на изучение его и нахождения ошибки нежели сделаете свой. Делается очень просто, создается массив а потом передается в шаблон, и в цикле перебирается.